# How to fix the finding "Validation.EncodingRequired"

Tags: java, encoding

The IBM AppScan Source pop up there's a vulnerability on my code "`bos.write(buff, 0, bytesRead);`", may I know is it a false alarm and how to fix it?

```
public static void download(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String       filePath)
{
BufferedInputStream bis = null;
BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
URL url = null;
try
{
  url = new URL(filePath);


  response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
  request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
  response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
  response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName(filePath));

  bis = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
  bos = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
  byte[] buff = new byte[2048];
  int bytesRead;

  while (-1 != (bytesRead = bis.read(buff, 0, buff.length))) {
    bos.write(buff, 0, bytesRead);
  }

}
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
  closeStream(bis);
  closeStream(bos);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found to use GZIPOutputStream instead of BufferOutputStream, which can be passed in AppScan Source. But not sure will there any side effect.